# Best 'logging' option on Amazon Cloud. RDS or SimpleDB?

Tags: logging, stateless, amazon-simpledb, amazon-rds

My site's architecture includes ASP.Net & MySQL. I am planning to deploy it on Amazon Cloud. This would mean EC2 instance(s) and RDS. My query is regarding logging.

I'm ensuring that my application is stateless, so logging on application tier is ruled out. All state/persistence goes into RDS. When it comes to logging, I am not sure if RDS is a good choice (just speculating). Since it is new and I'd be logging database exceptions also, logging into RDS my not be correct. I guess the best option at my disposal is SimpleDB.

I'm looking for recommendations to choose between RDS and SimpleDB for the purpose of logging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was also figuring out where to log in Amazon cloud and decided to do it into SimpleDB, because relational database is much too complicated for logging purposes. I use Java in this case and there's a ready-made [log appender for SimpleDB](http://code.google.com/p/simpledb-appender/). I tried to google for something similar for .net but didn't find any :(

So, I recommend SimpleDB over RDS.

---

**UPDATE** 2010-03-02:

SimpleDB has an attribute value length restriction of 1024 bytes. So, if you get longer log messages, this has to be somehow taken care of. One solution is to split the log message to multiple attributes (i.e. columns). There can be 256 attribute name-value pairs, which gives us plenty of room.